# implicit conversion of int to NSString is disallowed with arc in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios9.2

[image]
Could anybody suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve please explain

Comment: Please post the (relevant) *code* (and the exact error messages), not links to screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing curl url like this :-

```
NSString* curlURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?.....rpp=20&page=%d", 123];
```

Hope given string format helps you.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

a more elaborated question.
first a quick response:

You cannot call swift plain function from objC.
You can call methods but not plain f.

see below:

**// swift class:**

```
@objc class Klass: NSObject {

    var a = 100
    
     @objc public func F1()->String{
        return "F1"
    }

    
    @objc public func F2()->NSString{
        return "f2"
    }

}

func myF()->String{
    return "FFF"
}


func myG()->NSString{
    return "GGG"
}
```

**in objC:**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    Klass* k = [Klass new];
    
    NSString * s1 = [k F1];
    NSString * s2 = [k F2];

    s1 = k.F1;
    s2 = k.F2;
    
    NSString * sf = myF(); // ERROR! ... Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
    NSString * sg = myG(); // ERROR!     "      "   "
}
```

If you add a plain C code (adding includes and so on...)

## include "plainFunctions.h"

```
//file:plainFunctions.c
#include "plainFunctions.h"

int myN()
{
    return 100;
}
```

You can call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    int n = myN();
}
```

or even:

```
//h:
char * myC(void);


// objC:
    NSString * fromC = [NSString stringWithCString:myC() encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). That the message says `... disallowed with ARC` is a red herring, the issue here is you're assigning a number to an `NSString*`.

It's not entirely clear from your screenshot, which I summarise here:

```
NSString *currurl = (@"https://some-string-%d", 'abcd');
```

.. where it looks like you're trying to compose an `NSString*`.

However the compiler is evaluating an expression comprising an `NSString*`, the comma-operator and a character, where the result is the right hand operand of that comma operator. So it is trying to assign `abcd` to `currurl`.

Remember that characters are integer types in C based languages (same in Java), hence the complaint `Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *'`